# Jquery: Get favicon with full path

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, path, favicon

I want to grab the link of a favicon from a website with Jquery. I simply use `$('link[rel="shortcut icon"]').attr('href');` and it works fine.

But... I do not always have a complete path. For example I can have something like

```
http://mywebsite.com/myicon.ico
```

or only a relative path

```
/myicon.ico
```

I would like to always have the full path, even if the Url is coded as a relative path. Is there a simple solution to this?

*I use this as a Content Script in a Google Chrome Extension.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you use the `href` property of the node, you should always get an absolute path:

```
var url = $('link[rel="shortcut icon"]')[0].href;
```

Or:

```
var url = $('link[rel="shortcut icon"]').prop('href');
```

Or, in plain JavaScript:

```
var url = document.querySelector('link[rel="shortcut icon"]').href;
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the sites doesn't have common name for rel in link tag. 
Some have

```
<link rel="icon" href="https://pages.ebay.com/favicon.ico">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d">
```

So instead of matching exact rel tag its better if use regex inside the query selector

```
$("link:regex(rel, .*icon.*)").prop('href')
```

if this gives unmatched pseudo-class : regex exception, you can use this

```
$('link[rel~="icon"]').prop('href')
```