# How can I get the description and the url picture for a Google Chrome tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm having Google Chrome extension and I just want to know how I can store the description and url picture of the curent tab in a variable.

I have already storing the url and the title with these instructions:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    document.getElementById('currentLink').innerHTML = tab.url;
});


chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    document.getElementById('currentTitle').innerHTML = tab.title;
});
```

But still can't store the description and the url picture from the balise meta like this:

```
<meta name="description" content="Le Monde.fr - 1er site d'information. Les articles du journal et toute l'actualit&eacute; en continu : International, France, Soci&eacute;t&eacute;, Economie, Culture, Environnement, Blogs ...">


<meta property="og:image" content="http://s1.lemde.fr/medias/web/1.2.639/img/placeholder/opengraph.jpg">
```

Comment: Can you provide more details, like the site you are using?  What do you mean by URL picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the same extesion for Mozilla Firefox.. and I'm storing variables with this code

```
var x = content.document.getElementsByTagName("meta"); for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++) { if (x[i].getAttribute("property") !=null) { if (x[i].getAttribute("property").toLowerCase() == "og:url") var url = x[i].content; if (x[i].getAttribute("property").toLowerCase() == "og:description") var description = x[i].content; if (x[i].getAttribute("property").toLowerCase() == "og:title") var title = x[i].content; if (x[i].getAttribute("property").toLowerCase() == "og:image") var image = x[i].content; };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this jQuery solution:

```
var faviconUrl = $('link[rel="shortcut icon"]')[0].href;
```

Source: [Jquery: Get favicon with full path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220412/jquery-get-favicon-with-full-path)

Comment: Then it's not a favicon. But try `var imageUrl = $('link[property="og:image"]')[0].href;`